# Append results and show from which combination originated?

Tags: python, list, append, python-itertools

This is a classic Python example with `append` and a `for loop` but I can't figure out what needs to be changed in order to work.

I have these lines:

```
clf =  SVC(C=10,gamma=1,kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(vectors, df.type)
vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(df_test.news)
pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
metrics.f1_score(df_test.type, pred, average='macro')
```

the last line gives f1 score 0.95.

**Purpose**

I want to try different combinations for the first line (`clf`) and make it return the `f1 score` results (last line) for every combination.

Here is what I tried:

```
import itertools

clf=[]
mode=[]

ar=np.array(df_test.type)
for element in list(itertools.product(range(3),range(3))):
    c = element[0] #for each iteration will take a new value from the range
    g = element[1] #same here, and will replace the values c and g below
    try:
        clf.append(SVC(C=c,gamma=g,kernel='rbf').fit(vectors,df.type))
        vectors_test = vectorizer.transform(df_test.news)
        pred = clf.predict(vectors_test)
        metrics.f1_score(df_test.type, pred, average='macro')
        except:
            pass
```

This is kind of close I think. Can you help?

Comment: I haven't dug into your question closely enough but it may be helpful to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperparameter_optimization and do searches based on keywords such as "grid search" or "hyperparameter optimization".

Comment: This is what I tried first (grid search) but it couldn't work with these data and this is why I try to do it manually.